# ObjectDisposedException obtaining user name in SignalR event

Tags: vb.net, signalr

I'm logging current SignalR connections in a sql server database.  Records are added via the OnConnected and OnReconnected events and removed via the OnDisconnected event.

On deploying to our staging server I am now experiencing an intermittent issue fetching the username of the disconnected user.

This is using SignalR v2.0.3

```
Public Overrides Function OnDisconnected() As Threading.Tasks.Task
  Try

    Dim username As String = String.Empty
    Try
      username = Me.Context.User.Identity.Name  ' this is where the error occurs
    Catch ex As Exception
      _logger.LogWarning(ex, EventLogEntryType.Warning)
    End Try

    Dim connId = Me.Context.ConnectionId
    Dim referer = Me.Context.Headers("Referer")

    _connService.RemoveConnection(connId)

    Dim msg = New With {.username = username, .connectionId = connId, .referer = referer}
    Dim hub = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext(Of IncidentsHub)()
    hub.Clients.All.disconnectionEvent(msg)

  Catch ex As Exception
    _logger.LogWarning(ex, EventLogEntryType.Error)

  End Try

  Return MyBase.OnDisconnected()
End Function
```

I have had to wrap the offending line in an additional try/catch and accept that sometimes there will be no username returned.

The exception seen is:

```
MOAE - System.ObjectDisposedException: Safe handle has been closed
   at System.Runtime.InteropServices.SafeHandle.DangerousAddRef(Boolean& success)
   at Microsoft.Win32.Win32Native.GetTokenInformation(SafeTokenHandle TokenHandle, UInt32 TokenInformationClass, SafeLocalAllocHandle TokenInformation, UInt32 TokenInformationLength, UInt32& ReturnLength)
   at System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetTokenInformation(SafeTokenHandle tokenHandle, TokenInformationClass tokenInformationClass)
   at System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.get_User()
   at System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetName()
   at System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.get_Name()
   at MyProject.IncidentsHub.OnDisconnected() in C:\Projects\...\IncidentsHub.vb:line 95
```

Can anyone tell me why this is occurring and if there is a more reliable way to obtain this information?

Comment: @DavidWilliams No, sorry. The code remains pretty much as listed above.